# Dual norm of Weighted L1

Tags: duality-theorems, dual-spaces

I am trying to derive the dual of weighted $L_1$ norm. Assume weights are all non-negative.  Let $x \in R^2$

$$|| x ||_{1,w} = w_1 |x_1| + w_2 |x_2|   $$

How do weights affect the dual norm?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If the weighted $L_1[a,b]=\{ x(t) | \int_a^b w(t) |x(t)| dt< \infty\}$ where $w(t)\geq 0$, then it seems to me that the dual space would be $\{ x(t) | \sup_{t\in[a,b]}(  |x(t)|/w(t))< \infty\}$.